# How to include html in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a login form as a model and in which I have terms and conditions button and I want to show another model when I click on that terms.Therefore when I click on my terms buttons a html containing terms should be shown.

**My html :**

```
 <div class="col_full">
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-class="{'error': submitted && registerLoginForm.terms.$error.required}"  name="terms" value="check"   id="agree"  ng-model="register.terms" required/> I agree to the XpertDox <a href="#" ng-click="termsandPolicy('terms')">Terms of Use</a> & <a href="#" ng-click="termsandPolicy('privacy')">Privacy Policy.</a>
 </div>
```

my terms html is terms-model.html

my js,

```
$scope.termsandPolicy = function(type){
            $timeout(function(){
                if(type == 'terms'){
                    $('#terms-model').modal('show');
                }

            }, 1000); 

        }
```

But I am not sure that where I should include this terms-model. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: For the terms and conditions modal to be displayed you must include it on your html page, where the input tag is written. Otherwise it will not be available and will not be displayed

Comment: how can i include?Is this the way  <div ng-include="'app/templates/terms-model.html'"></div>

Comment: you can use custom directive for that purpose. put all your html code in templates section of directive and restrict it as elements then you can include as an html element
<directiveName></directiveName>

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap modal dialog if u're using bootstrap. Add ng-include in your html like below examples.

**Html**

```
<ng-include="'template/terms-model.html'"></ng-include>
```

**terms-model.html**

```
<div id="termsModal" class="modal" role="dialog"
     tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
           <!-- Place ur content here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
$scope.termsandPolicy = function(type){
     // Show modal by Id
     $('#termsModal').modal('show');
}
```